# Optimize view that dynamically choose a table or another

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

So the problem is that I have three huge table with same structure, and I need to show the results of one of them depending on result from another query.

So my order table looks like that:

```
code   order
A      0
B      2
C      1
```

And I need to retrieve data from `t_results`

My approach (which is working) looks like this:

```
select *
from t_results_a
where 'A' in (
  select code
  from t_order
  where order = 0
)

UNION ALL

select *
from t_results_b
where 'B' in (
  select code
  from t_order
  where order = 0
)

UNION ALL

select *
from t_results_c
where 'C' in (
  select code
  from t_order
  where order = 0
)
```

Is there anyway to not scan all three tables, as I am working with Athena so I can't program?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that changing your database schema is not an option.
If it were, you could use one database table and add a `CODE` column whose value would be either *A*, *B* or *C*.

Basically the result of the SQL query on your `ORDER` table determines which other database table you need to query. For example, if `CODE` in table `ORDER` is *A*, then you have to query table `T_RESULTS_A`.

You wrote in your question

> I am working with Athena so I can't program

I see that there is both an [ODBC driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-odbc.html) and a [JDBC driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) for Athena, so you can program with either .NET or Java. So you could write code that queries the `ORDER` table and use the result of that query to build another query string to query just the relevant table.

Another thought I had was *dynamic SQL*. Oracle database supports it. I can create a string containing variables where one variable is the database table name and have Oracle interpret the string as SQL and execute it.  I briefly searched the Internet to see whether Athena supports this (as I have no experience with Athena) but found nothing - which doesn't mean to say that it does not exist.